# Android: Swipe Next Steps?

Tags: android

I am trying to do something similar to the starbucks app. In the starbucks app, you can select the gift card you want to use and swipe to another card.

[image: Screenshot of App]

I also want to create an indicator on the botton like in the starbucks app. Also, I want to create this on the fly.

What is my next step. I was thinking of using ViewPagerIndicator. Am I on the right track? If not, please advise what I should use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) is the right library to use. In particular, you need the `CirclePageIndicator`

Comment: is it possible to use this library to dynamically create/remove fragments?

Comment: The library itself doesn't have anything to do with fragments. Read up on ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter.